# How to increase font size in Emacs, running on Ubuntu BASH shell on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, bash, emacs, fonts, windows-10-v1607

After the "anniversary update" Windows 10 allows the user to run a Ubuntu based BASH shell from within Windows 10.

I have installed emacs on the BASH shell using the `apt-get install`. When I open emacs the font size is too small.  I have been using emacs for quite sometime now and I know that using the `C-x C-+` will increase the font size (scale the font) in the GUI mode in Emacs.

However, I could not make that command to work in the present case.

I have tried the following already:

1. `C-x C-+`
2. `M-x text-scale-increase`
3. `M-x text-scale-decrease` or `M-x text-scale-adjust`

Nothing has worked so far.
So my question is, *how can I increase (or scale) the font size to a higher or lower size than the default one?*

Comment: The answers to, [Font size of emacs in ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/518372/font-size-of-emacs-in-ubuntu), are applicable.

Comment: It isn't just this shorcut, [Windows 10 linux bash shell ctrl+space doesn't set mark in Emacs](http://superuser.com/questions/1088250/windows-10-linux-bash-shell-ctrlspace-doesnt-set-mark-in-emacs?rq=1), requires a workaround for the time being.  You can also wait, for this issue and/or bug, to be fixed by Canonical

Comment: Let it be Canonical or MS, either way - the user is affected.  Also, this [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/518372/font-size-of-emacs-in-ubuntu?answertab=active#tab-top) is more relevant. But i'm unable to locate the `.Xresources` file for Emacs within this shell.

Comment: you will get your answer here...I did get it too https://morgansimonsen.com/2016/08/08/fun-with-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/